# Configure sendmail to send mail only to local mail address

Tags: email, localhost, sendmail, lamp

I need to configure *sendmail* in order to test websites and app mail function locally;

I wish that if on production a *mail()* function sends a mail to *user@hisdomain.com*, the same code tested locally sends a mail to *myfolder@localhost* in order to check messages details, functionalities and so on.

I'm on a **LAMP** machine.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You may configure sendmail to deliver all outgoing mail to local mailbox/alias.
It should catch all message to non local mailboxes.

`sendmail.mc` file (used to generate `sendmail.cf` file):

```
define(`SMART_HOST`,`local:myfolder`)dnl
```

Restart/reload sendmail daemon after compiling new `sendmail.cf` file from `sendmail.mc` file.